# Remove question mark from URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I don't have much experience with htaccess and mod_rewrite or anything, but how would one remove the ? from a URL that looks something like: `site.com/?page` so it looks like `site.com/page` ?

I'm trying this at the moment:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(index\.php)?\?([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

But it just redirects everything to just `site.com` index page, without anything else in the url.

Comment: Please do not use pseudo-tags in your title.  We have *real* tags.

Comment: What does the first `RewriteCond` mean ?

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im Defines condition for mod_rewrite? I think the expression `/(index\.php)?\?([^&\ ]+)` might be wrong but I'm not sure...

Answer (score 0):

Your backreference is incorrect. You want to match the 2nd grouping from `%{THE_REQUEST}`, not the first (which is `index.php`). So your first rule should look like:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(index\.php)?\?([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%2? [L,R=301]
# 2 here--------^
```

The 2nd grouping would be the `([^&\ ]+)` match.